# Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets isn't working

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, conditional-formatting, tic-tac-toe

I'm trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game in a Google Sheets but I'm having trouble with the conditional formatting. I want the cell chosen by the computer to have a blue background/fill.
[image: Screenshot]
I tried the formula manually and it works, so I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula

```
=COLUMN()&","&ROW()=$H$2
```

[image]